# Is "The question" at the front of this sentence extraneous?

Tags: conjunctions

Is "The question" in:

> "The question whether we should go or stay comes next."

extraneous?

[LanguageTool](https://languagetool.org/) suggests to remove "***The question***" from the sentence. However, I think "The question" is fine in there. Why do you think Language Tool is suggesting that?

Comment: You have linked to the tool, but we don't see your sentence anymore. So, what was the sentence?

Comment: Please don't put the first part of your question in the title anymore. Give it a meaningful title instead.

Comment: Did you try ""The question whether we should go or stay comes next."" in LT?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a preposition after the word *question*. Normally one would use *of*:

> The question *of* whether we should go or stay comes next.

Or, you can put the actual question in quotes:

> The question “Should we go or stay?” comes next.

Answer (score 0):

If you remove "The question", then you loose most of the meaning of the sentence.

You may rephrase it as:

> We should decide next **whether we should go or stay**.